# Getting capybara and cucumber to log more information

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm having problems with my [cucumber/capybara setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964344/selenium-doesnt-work-with-cucumber-capybara-out-of-the-box-macosx) and was wondering...

How can I get more information out of cucumber and capybara to see what's going on?

I've tried running

```
bundle exec cucumber features/myfeature.feature -v -b -x
```

But that just shows which rb files are loaded and which feature is being loaded. I want to know what on earth it is running. All it shows me is:

```
F_______________F
```

Which is completely unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of information are you looking to see?

You can try adding the `--format=pretty` option - this will print out each step as it's being processed, with the file location of the step definition that matches it, so you can see the status of each step (passed, failed, skipped, pending, etc.)

Comment: Was hoping to see more information between the cucumber and capybara layer. I did find a way to get more info but it involves using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I miss some real logging support in Cucumber, in order to debug steps, but it seems the current way to log from steps is to "announce" messages. Announcements are turned on with the @announce tag. Try tagging your feature/scenario with @announce, that's the best option I've discovered so far.