# Capybara-webkit raises Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, acceptance-testing, capybara-webkit

I got following message from webkit driver in my rspec:

```
Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:
Unable to load URL: http://127.0.0.1:44923/posts
```

Few days ago it worked. The problem is with `save_page` method.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Nope. It simply started working again.

Comment: If it happens again, does this solution work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5032285/237958

Answer (score 7):

I've had similar error messages when my page was raising an error. You should check manually that this is not the case by starting a server in testing mode (`rails s -e test`) and accessing the page yourself.

Comment: I ran in to this issue for the same reason. To debug you can also change the call to 'visit foo_path' to 'get foo_path' and you should then see any exception raised by the page in the test output.

Comment: I've been taking this same approach myself recently, @Marc-André Lafortune. Good advice. I'd add that you'll want to fire up that server after you've run your spec so the database's most recent state will be available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you don't have any other error in your application that could prevent Capybara from loading the page. Last time I got it, I realized that there was a 500 error page and that was why Capybara raised Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing gem `thin` from your bundle completely.

Even if it is in `:development` or `:production` group only!

Answer (score 0):

In your `test.rb`:

set `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true`

and you will see the exception that caused the `WebkitInvalidResponseError`